# VueJS on-click event not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I couldn't manage to make it work. v-on:click event is not invoking the method on Vue instance. Here is the codes:

```
<div id="app">
    <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="postEventData">
        <i class="icon wb-share"></i> Publish
    </button>
</div>
```

Vue instance:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        someData: 'fooBar'
    },
    methods: {
        postEventData: function () {
            axios.post('/foobar', vm._data);
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `v-on:click` is getting called just fine. Look at this fiddle for example https://fiddle.jshell.net/v1qpt8d8/1/

Comment: You need to reference `this` in your `postEventData` method, not `vm`

Comment: Thanks but even I copy paste the jsfiddle, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change this `axios.post('/foobar', vm._data);`

to this: `axios.post('/foobar', this.data);`

Comment: I tried regular `onclick="vm.postEventData()"` and it is working fine. However, when I changed `vm._data` to `this.data` it is not working too. I couldn't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

[I'm not seeing anything broken with your code.](https://fiddle.jshell.net/v1qpt8d8/2/)

That said, it would be better practice to use `this` to reference the Vue instance instead of `vm`. But, you would still need to reference the `_data` property of your Vue instance to get the `data` object (`this.data` is going to be `undefined`).

However, while you *can* reference your `data` object via `this._data`,  it's a code smell. Your Vue instance's data properties are meant to be accessed individually directly off of `this`. Accessing the whole object breaks that paradigm.

If you are trying to submit `{ someData: 'fooBar' }` in your post request, make a data property for that (say `postData`) and reference it via `this.postData`:

```
 var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        postData: { someData: 'fooBar' }
    },
    methods: {
        postEventData: function () {
            axios.post('/foobar', this.postData);
        }
    }
});
```

---

Your template with `v-on:click="postEventData"` is fine.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information! I will try your suggestions on my code and share the output in the comments later.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this is what worked for me if someone else is stuck

button click event was actually trying to submit form since it was contained in a form element. So in order to make it call the method I had to do `@click.prevent="myMethod()"`

`.prevent` is the key. It acted as `event.preventDefault()`